Why do I get validation errors when running Azure DevOps YAML pipelines from az CLI?
I have some YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps that I want to run with az CLI, from my local PC.
But I get the following error when I try to run the pipeline:
ERROR: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.

The weird thing is, the pipeline is validated according to DevOps:

The az CLI runs have worked before. So when did this stop working then? We created a new Service Connection recently. After that, the az CLI keeps returning validation errors for the YAML pipelines. Is there any way that I can revalidate the pipelines so that az CLI can run them? Please don't tell me I have to recreate the 40 pipelines again, but if I have to, I have to accept it I guess.
Thanks!

What happens if you queue and run one of these builds manually?

Also, consider adding the --debug option when running your Azure DevOps CLI command as it might display more details about the issue.

How was your new Azure Resource Manager service connection created? Have you tried to click on the Verify button to see if there is any error when Editing the ARM service connection?

@RuiJarimba When I run the pipeline manually in the DevOps web, the pipeline works

@RuiJarimba ok I will try it with the debug option thank you.

Can you double check if it was indeed the ARM service connection that was invalid? You may create a new pipeline with the AzureCLI task referencing the same ARM service connection with a very simple command like az account show to see if the issue was reproducible.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT the verify is green and works

You mean the ARM service connection can pass verification and the pipeline works when you run the pipeline manually? Then how was the issue reproduced? Can you please share more detailed steps, with some screenshots? Please don't forget to remove any sensitive informaiton.

Is it a YAML pipeline? When the error was reproduced, was the pipeline referencing the same branch as that of the successful manual build consumed?

When I run the pipeline manually in the DevOps web, the pipeline works - did you use exactly the same branch and the same options as compared to using the Azure CLI?

Turns out I had done a replace all in Visual Code across my entire project where  I hade replaced "test" with "TEST". Since the Python script I use to trigger the pipelines, the branch name which was "test", was replaced with "TEST", so it didn't match the branch name any longer since it's case sensitive.
So it was just a mistake on my part while editing my code.
